# Is it okay to let dogs play in a backyard with a pool unsupervised?

Tags: dogs

Our 6 month Golden Retriever really enjoys playing in the back yard that has a pool. She has not been in the pool yet but does not seem interested in it either way.

She plays in the back yard but I worry if she accidentally fell in the pool, she may not find the steps out. I will teach her how to swim this summer but the real issue is getting back out.

Is a pool ramp the best strategy here?

Are there any other ways to keep a dog safe with a pool?

Comment: As you say, the best way for a dog to get out is a submerged step or shelf (not ladder) that they can easily get all four paws onto so they can jump the rest of the way from there. Beyond that: ___nobody___ should be swimming without a buddy watching them, and if you care about the dog that includes the dog. Accidents can happen even to expert swimmers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend it. I lived in Arizona for a while and we had a pool. We fenced it, but also put the dog into the pool from different sides and made sure he always knew where the exit stairs were. So if you really have to, my recommendation is to only do it if it's a pool where the dog can exit by him/herself, and ideally fence the pool. It is common that dogs die because they drown in pools, so I'd be careful.

Answer (score 0):

I would be very cautious has you're saying that she's never been in the pool. That means you have no idea how she would react.

Why don't you try to see how it would go immediately?

Even if I'm quite sure she wouldn't drown herself she could "panic".

My dog is quite confortable in the water but if he fell in the water he'll try to get out right where he is, without trying to swim a bit to get out elsewhere easily. So a ramp is not of any help in a situation like that.

Comment: This answer might be a bit understated, a quick search of google finds multiple references for preventing dogs from drowning in pools and some occurrences.

Comment: @cedric-h: its been winter and the water temperature is way too cold for her..it is now finally warming up